# How to Retrieve value from database which not belongs to table column in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm calling this stored procedure to check where `Username, Email Address and Phone Number` is already register or not. if this values are not registered in my database then this `Stored Procedure` return `Available` Value

```
Create procedure [dbo].[proc_CheckingUserEmailMobile]( @chkUserEmailPhone varchar(35))
as 
  begin
   declare @User varchar(35)
   declare @Email varchar(35)
   declare @Phone varchar(15)
   declare @StatusAvailablevarchar(15)
   set @StatusAvailable='NotAvailable'
   set @User=(select username from users where username=@chkUserEmailPhone)
   set @Email=(select emailid from users where emailid=@chkUserEmailPhone)
   set @Phone=(select phone from users where phone=@chkUserEmailPhone)
   if(@User is not null)
    begin
      select Username=@User
    end
   else if(@Email is not null)
    begin
     select Email=@Email
    end
    else if (@Phone is not null)
     begin
      select Phone=@Phone
     end
     else
      begin
       select StatusAvailable=@StatusAvailable
      end
  end
```

## In Asp.net Page :

```
DataSet dsUEM = businessLogic.CheckUsernameEmailPhoneBAL(ChkUserBO);
            if (dsUEM.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dsUEM.Tables[0].Rows[0]["StatusAvailable"].ToString() != "NotAvailable")
                {
                }
}
```

## Error :

Column `StatusAvailable` does not belong to table Table.
Please any one suggest me how to achieve this...

Comment: If the user is not available there is no column named StatusAvailable. However, I suggest you to use an output parameter or a return value parameter

Comment: @sri did you exceuted the SP , with the values you passing from UI and verfied its o/p?

Comment: Why use this string result in the first place?  Why not just select the count of matching records?  If a record is found, it exists.  If no record is found, it doesn't exist.  It seems this entire stored procedure can be replaced with a simple `SELECT` statement, and the entire nested `if` in the C# code becomes unnecessary.

Comment: @sri , even you select seems will not be returning a column by name Statusavailble because it has other else statement where they are not retuning the same column name i.e.`statusavailable`

Comment: i tried with count(*) its working fine, but my requirement is if user already registered in my site even though he's trying to register with same username at the time of registration its check whether user changed username or not

Answer (score 1):

This whole setup seems to just be making this logic a lot more complicated than it needs to be.  All you need to do is check if a matching record exists or not.  That's one `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT id FROM users
WHERE username = @chkUserEmailPhone 
   OR emailid = @chkUserEmailPhone
   OR phone = @chkUserEmailPhone
```

If there's a matching record, the resulting record count will be greater than 0.  So...

```
DataSet dsUEM = businessLogic.CheckUsernameEmailPhoneBAL(ChkUserBO);
if (dsUEM.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    // a matching record was found
}
```

(Now, the fact that the one input value can be in any of those three columns seems like another problem entirely.  But that's outside the scope of what's being asked.)

Comment: i want to check user already exist or not, if he exist then i want to get that username and stored in Session["userExist"] because if user not changed he's username in textbox trying to register with same username then i want to check `txtusername.Text==Session["userExist"]` if condition is true then i want to give error message `Username not available` Similliary i want to do same operation `Email and Phone Number`

Comment: @Sri: Instead of selecting just the `id` you can select the entire record in that case.  (`SELECT * ...`)  Then you'd have any and all matching user records (regardless of which field matched) and could examine that data in your code to display any custom error messages.

Answer (score 1):

To start I really suggest to change the stored procedure. As now it executes three queries just to check for the existance of the data over the same table

```
Create procedure [dbo].[proc_CheckingUserEmailMobile]( @chkUserEmailPhone varchar(35))
as 
  begin
   if EXISTS(select 1 from users 
      where username=@chkUserEmailPhone OR 
            emailid=@chkUserEmailPhone OR
            phone=@chkUserEmailPhone)
       SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
  end
```

In this way the stored procedure returns just one row with one column, as ExecuteScalar requires. The return is 1 if one of your fields contains the value passed as parameter or 0 if no field matches the parameter

Now in your BAL methods  you run an ExecuteScalar call

```
public bool IsUserAvailable(string chkUserEmailPhone)
{
   using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(....))
   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_CheckingUserEmailMobile", cnn))
   {
       cnn.Open();
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@chkUserEmailPhone", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = chkUserEmailPhone;
       int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

       // SP return 1 if the data exists, so we need to negate 
       // to get true if the user data is available for a new record.
       return !(result == 1)
   }
}
```

Comment: Steve i want to check user already exist or not, if he exist then i want to get that username and stored in Session["userExist"] because if user not changed he's username in textbox trying to register with same username then i want to check `txtusername.Text==Session["userExist"]` if condition is true then i want to give error message `Username not available ' Similliary i want to do same operation `Email and Phone Number `

Comment: Let me understand what is your goal. Do you want to stop a user changing its username, email or phone if there is another user with that data? In this case you need to pass also the primary key of the current user to avoid a positive match on itself, while if this is an insert operation you just check if there is a match somewhere in your database

Comment: i'm using Single StoredProcedure for Checking `Username with txtusername_TextChanged(){ }` and `Email with txtemail_TextChanged{}` Phone with `txtphone_TextChanged(){ }`

Comment: I would avoid to put call like these in the TextChanged event. While the user types you constantly check the database. Let's end the input and check with a button click

Comment: how can i check 3 field at a time with button click